# Understanding Queues and Scheduler on Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am experimenting on how to write jobs on Laravel.

Following the Laravel documentation, I created a simple job that sends email using mail:queue.

I also added a cron job that will call the scheduler every minute which in turn will run the job every 5 minutes.

Everything works fine when I manually run the command queue:listen.

Later I added a print statement inside the scheduler and I found a strange issue.

Whenever I run the queue:listen from the terminal, I see the print message that is inside the schedule function and it gets printed every 5 seconds.

So my question is does **queue:listen** call the schedule function? If yes, why do we need to add **schedule:run** as a cron job?

The code that I used:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){     
    error_log("inside scheduler");
    $schedule->call(function () {
        dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SendEmail);
    })->everyFiveMinutes();              
}
```

This is the command I ran on the terminal.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Output that I get (every 5 seconds)

inside scheduler

inside scheduler

inside scheduler
...

Can someone explain what is happening here?

-**Adding the job code for better understanding**
SendEmail.php

```
 public function handle() {
 //do some task here
 Mail::queue("emails.send_update", [], function($message) {
  $message->to("someone@somedomain.com");
  $message->subject('Status has been updated');
 });
 }
```

Comment: Have you get any solutions. And I also confused why the `schedule()` function is executed by the `queue:listen`.

Answer (score 10):

Queues and scheduling are different things.

**[Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)**
You can set up a mail queue, that you run on the server. This is always listening. If you add an email to the mail queue, your queue function will execute the sending of the mail as soon as it can: it just does this on a different thread.

**[Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling)**
This is a way in Laravel for organising cron jobs. Laravel suggests you setup one cron command on your server that executes every minute called `schedule:run`. In this command, Laravel then looks at the scheduling scripts you've setup and their conditions, and executes the appropriate ones for you when they need to be executed.

When it comes to your mail task: you should be adding the mail to the jobs queue, and leaving it like that. Don't involve scheduling. Then on your server you would just have the queue running with `queue:listen`: when a mail gets added to the queue, it will be sent immediately.

On your server also setup the cron command for any scheduling scripts (as described under *scheduling: starting the scheduler*), but you can then forget that the cron was ever setup. Then you can just create your own scheduling scripts to be executed at certain times and Laravel will work its magic for you.

**Updated response**:
In your SendEmail.php function, you need to handle the task of a mail being sent: something like

```
public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $mailer->send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $this->user], function ($m) {
        //
    });
}
```

At the moment, every 5 minutes you're adding a new job to the queue, but your job is to queue the email message. So you're effectively continually queuing messages but never really executing them.

Comment: Hi Tom. I am actually doing what you have mentioned. The requirement is to have a job that does a particular task and then sends an email. It needs to run every 5 minutes. I also have setup cron jobs to call the scheduler as you mentioned. Everything works as described.  The thing that I am not able to understand is since queue and scheduler different, why is queue:listen calling the schedule function? As you can see in my OP, the error_log prints the message every 5 secs.

Comment: I don't know queue:listen execute the `schedule()` function in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `queue:listen` will execute partly of 'schedule()' function in Kernel.php, which make it output contents periodically in your code. Change `queue:listen` to `queue:work` will solve this issue.

Refer this [laravel cannot run scheduled command, while queue:listen run schedule() periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47548220/6521116) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47567937/6521116) for more information.